# Getting segmentation fault while compiling solidity contract

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, solc

Getting segmentation fault when compiling a simple contract on geth on OSX Yosemite

```
web3.eth.getCompilers();
["Solidity"]
source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
"contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test
solc: signal: segmentation fault

    at InvalidResponse (<anonymous>:-81662:-45)
    at send (<anonymous>:-156322:-45)
    at solidity (<anonymous>:-133322:-45)
    at <anonymous>:1:12
```

my geth version is 1.3.6 and solc is

> Version: 0.3.1-12797ed6/RelWithDebInfo-Darwin/appleclang/JIT linked to libethereum-1.2.3-3f84edc3/RelWithDebInfo-Darwin/appleclang/JIT

NOTE:
It also raises error when running `solc` on its own

```
19:49:55-makoto~/src/webthree-helpers (develop)$ cat contract.sol 
contract test {
    function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) {
        return a * 7;
    }
}
19:51:15-makoto~/src/webthree-helpers (develop)$ solc --bin -o solcoutput contract.sol
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: can you post some code plz?

Comment: `segmentation fault` appears when we have some bad sectors, can you please try re-install the solidity?

Comment: Can you even run `solc` by itself?  Probably will crash too and need to re-install it as @NikhilM suggests.

Comment: I reinstalled cpp-ethereum 2 times and ethereum(aka geth) once.

Comment: same error when running solc on its own

Answer (score 5):

Compile it using the latest solc version at http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/.  If you don't get good output, then you have a bug you can file with the solidity folks.

I had a segfault back in January, upgrading to the latest version of Solidity fixed it.   Thanks to the advice on the gitter thread, which was "try browser-solidity and report back", my issue was resolved quickly.

Comment: This does not solves OPs question, but it is a workaround yes.

Comment: yeah you are probably right, I saw the gitter thread. He's in shared lib hell it looks like to me.  I've stayed in javascript land and avoided all the binary and library issues with webthree_umbrella and Mix. I'd rather have NPM package issues than shared library issues any day of the week...