# Link solc with geth problem

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, blockchain, installation, solc

After upgrading to geth 1.4.4 I am no longer able to from to reference the compiler from geth.

The solc compiler is installed in /usr/local/bin but this is what I get when I check for available compilers:

```
> eth.getCompilers();
I0520 10:22:45.501340 common/compiler/solidity.go:114] solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.2-7a51852a/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT

path: /usr/local/bin/solc

[]
```

Then I try to set the compiler  path again:

```
> admin.setSolc("/usr/local/bin/solc")
I0520 10:25:49.234999 common/compiler/solidity.go:114] solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.2-7a51852a/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT

path: /usr/local/bin/solc
"solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface\nVersion: 0.3.2-7a51852a/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT\n\npath: /usr/local/bin/solc"
```

When I check the compilers again I still get:

```
> eth.getCompilers();
[]
```

I get the same using:

```
> web3.eth.getCompilers();
[]
```

I have reinstalled go-ethereum, npm.

Can anybody give me a hint of what to do or where to look to look.

I had no problems before upgrading to geth 1.4.4

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

Segmentation fault with solc version 0.3.2-7a51852a/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT <strike>, fixed with later updated version</strike>.

**UPDATE 26/06/2016**

This is a bug in the Solidity compiler.

Here is a quick test:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ echo '' | solc
Unknown exception during compilation.
```

See [`eth.compile.solidity` fails with solc version 0.3.5 #2703](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2703), which links to [Exception on compilation from stdin #651](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/651).

And the issue [Fix crash for input from stdin. #652](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/652) has been fixed, but will take an unknown (hopefully short) amount of time to make it into the repository packages.

This is the code change for the fix - [Fix crash for input from stdin. #652 - Files changed](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/652/files).

You can try installing the previous version of `solc`.

Or one workaround offered in the first link above:

> For anyone who wants a temporary workaround, you can clone this repo: https://github.com/mattdf/solidity-static and do a build in docker, then copy the solc file to your install. It makes a statically compiled build of solc so it should work on most distros.

---

## Details

### Check Solidity Compiler Within `geth`

I just checked by installation (Linux) and the output that you are getting is consistent with the output I get, but the compiler works correctly.

Run the test below to check if your compiler is configured correctly.

I'm using the following code:

```
contract Test { 
    function double(int a) constant returns(int) {
        return 2*a;
    } 
}
```

I've flattened the code above to:

```
> var testSource='contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }'
undefined
```

I've tried compiling the code using the following statement:

```
> var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);
undefined
```

And checked the results of the compilation:

```
> testCompiled
{
  Test: {
    code: "0x6060604052602a8060106000396000f3606060405260e060020a60003504636ffa1caa8114601a575b005b6002600435026060908152602090f3",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}],
      compilerOptions: "--bin --abi --userdoc --devdoc --add-std --optimize -o /tmp/solc935251869",
      compilerVersion: "0.3.2",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {}
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.3.2",
      source: "contract Test {  function double(int a) constant returns(int) { return 2*a; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And if you want to check if the code runs correctly:

```
> var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.Test.info.abiDefinition);
var test = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.Test.code, gas: 2000000}, 
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
...
Contract mined! Address: 0x5e3361efa79827d8a53a397b454770c6816585d7
> test.double(5)
10
```

### Check Solidity Compiler

If you are still encountering problems, let's try compiling the source code outside `geth`.

Save the following code into Test.sol:

```
contract Test { 
    function double(int a) constant returns(int) {
        return 2*a;
    } 
}
```

From your terminal, you should be able to run the following commands if your solidity compiler is working correctly:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ solc --bin Test.sol

======= Test =======
Binary: 
606060405260728060106000396000f360606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900480636ffa1caa146037576035565b005b604b60048080359060200190919050506061565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b6000816002029050606d565b91905056

user@Kumquat:~$ solc --abi Test.sol

======= Test =======
Contract JSON ABI
[{"constant":true,"inputs":  [{"name":"a","type":"int256"}],"name":"double","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"int256"}],"type":"function"}]
```

If the commands above do not produce similar output, there is something not quite right with your `solc` binary.

### Check `web3.js`

You have an error message that includes the text `web3.js`. The problem could be with this module. I'll update when I've researched it a bit more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks ofr answer. I am getting an error when I try to compile:
"solc: signal: segmentation fault

    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:20

>"

Comment: Just confirming that you are not adding the `>` at the beginning of each statement? This is the prompt in `geth`.

Comment: Hi, I have compiled many contracts before. So no problem with that :-)

Comment: I have also reinstalled cpp-ethereum (which installs the solc). I think it may be a problem with the node.js but not sure

Comment: Yup. Can you check that you can compile the code from your command line (outsite `geth`)?

Comment: Hi, No In fact I get this error when compiling directly like you indicated: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: But I guess that eth.getCompilers(); gives me an empty array of compilers [] is also en issue?

Comment: I don't believe so. The empty array `[]`must be like the `undefined` message. Does `solc` from your command line run at all? Without any parameters? And with the `--help` parameter?

Comment: Yes: solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.3.2-7a51852a/Release-Darwin/appleclang/JIT

Comment: Possibly related issue to [Getting segmentation fault while compiling solidity contract](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/getting-segmentation-fault-while-compiling-solidity-contract). Also see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/477 and  https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/573 .

Comment: Thanks for your help, but no luck so far. I will try to build the solc from source since reinstalling cpp-ethereum with brew did not help

Comment: I reinstalled cpp-ethereum today and now the compiler works and also inside geth. The array of compilers inside geth still returns [] but it works. I guess there has been an update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I try to compile the contract, I get the following error message: exec: "solc": executable file not found in $PATH
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:20 Can someone help?

Comment: @Physes try
sudo apt-get update and then
sudo apt-get install solc