# Buliding geth from source does not make Solidity available

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, command-line

I've made a fresh install of *go-ethereum* from source on Ubuntu and Fedora, launched it and expected to find Solidity available when doing `eth.getCompilers()`, but I get an empty list instead.

I have then installed Solidity explicitly, as described in the tutorial [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html), restarted `geth`, but that changed nothing. I installed the package to be available globally with `npm -g` and I can see the package being available if I try importing it from a console node session.

I am not using the c++ client, too, so I don't have the `solc` exectuable installed, but I seem to understand that it is not needed if I do the `npm` installation.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link solc with geth problem](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/link-solc-with-geth-problem)

Comment: eth.compilers return an empy list even if it's installed, see the topic just above ;)

Comment: just for reference solc comes with the cpp client, not geth, but your install with npm should be ok

Comment: Thanks @euri10 but I believe this is a different problem. My best guess, given that the ```node``` executable *can* find Solidity, is that the ```geth``` executable is not using the NODE_PATH environment variable, hence can't find the npm installation of Solidity.

Answer (score 2):

`eth.getCompilers()` returns an empty list even if installed.

You can try :

```
➜  ~ which solc
/usr/local/bin/solc
```

then in geth

```
> admin.setSolc("/usr/local/bin/solc")
```

Following your edit, if you just want to use the npm package you wont be able to compile in geth, but still you can use it in a script like described in the [package doc](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) :

```
var solc = require('solc');
var input = "contract x { function g() {} }";
var output = solc.compile(input, 1); // 1 activates the optimiser
for (var contractName in output.contracts) {
    // code and ABI that are needed by web3
    console.log(contractName + ': ' + output.contracts[contractName].bytecode);
    console.log(contractName + '; ' + JSON.parse( output.contracts[contractName].interface));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @euri10 but didn't you just write that the ```solc``` executable is part of the c++ client distribution only? Do I need to install both the go and the c++ clients if I want to use Solidity within the ```geth``` console? In addition to that, the ```npm``` installation does not give me a ```solc``` executable, just libraries I can use in node.

Comment: effectively if you want to try the executable within geth you'll have to install solc which comes with the c++ bundle, apologies, I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 2):

So, it looks like the standalone Solidity compiler `solc` is only available as part of the Ethereum C++ command line tools.

This means that if you want to use `solc` from within `geth` you need to install both the Go tools - that give you `geth` and the C++ tools, that give you `solc`.

This looks very odd to me, particularly considering that the C++ tools are a secondary project that [went through some hard times and is apparently being rebooted](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/index.html#history-of-the-code).

So, what is one supposed to use today as the leading Solidity compiler? Perhaps the [NodeJS console](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/index.html#running).

Comment: I'm following the C++ development very closely and they are currently in a process of breaking up the C++ project in stand alone forks for eth, ethminer, solidity etc. pp. Stay tuned, will take a couple of weeks though, but you will be able to install solidity only by then.